# How do I go about sealing grout between porcelain floor tiles without affecting their appearance?

Tags: bathroom, shower, sealing, grout, tiling

Having my bathroom remodeled and chose a Porcelain Mosaic Hex tiles in Matte Finish for the shower floor. The manufacturer of the tiles said the Porcelain tiles do not need to be sealed. But I am more concerned about the grout. I plan on using unsanded grout.

Can I just apply a sealer over it all without having to worry about hazing or discoloration on the tile as it would be pretty hard to just hit the grout only on 1 inch hex tiles?

Or do I just not seal it because they are Porcelain and the grout is unsanded?

Comment: Might be a place to use epoxy grout.

Comment: If your porcelain tile is glazed, the sealer shouldn't affect it.

Comment: Epoxy grout has its benefits, but it’s h#%^ to apply. You’d want experienced hands doing it if you choose that path.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can simply wipe grout sealer off the tile glaze as you work. Sealer penetrates the grout, so wiping the tile doesn't affect the seal quality or appearance. Should you miss some you can probably wipe it up later with a solvent such as acetone.

You should seal grout in a shower to prevent stains and mildew. Follow the manufacturer's instructions.